# On Success URL redirect not working for custom view in django-allauth

Tags: django, django-views, django-allauth

I've created my own class LocalSignup which extends the base django-allauth SignupView class with my own form and my own validation logic. The problem is that on success I cannot get the view to redirect to anything but the django `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL` in my settings.py. I have included a `success_url` field in my class based view; I have tried overriding the `get_success_url` function (see below); I have also tried passing my on success redirect using  `LocalSignup.as_view(success_url="/add_account_select/")`. None have worked. Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

```
class LocalSignup(SignupView):
    form_class = AllAuthUserForm
    template_name = 'signup/social_login.html'
    success_url = '/add_account_select/'  #reverse_lazy('add_account_select')    

    def get_success_url(self):
        return '/add_account_select/'  #reverse('add_account_select')

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # self.sociallogin = request.session.get('socialaccount_sociallogin')
        return super(LocalSignup, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def form_valid(self, form):
        ret = super(LocalSignup, self).form_valid(form)
        ### MY FORM VALIDATION LOGIC
        return ret

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        ret = super(LocalSignup, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        ret.update(dict(username=self.sociallogin.account.user.first_name,
                        photo_url=self.sociallogin.account.get_avatar_url() ))
        return ret
```

Comment: Just to be sure: did you alter the standard url routing such that the signup view is actually using your signup view and not the standard one? I would suggest you put a breakpoint (`import pdb; pdb.set_trace()`) in your method to see if it gets invoked. If it is invoked you can step through the code to see where things go wrong. I am interested in hearing the outcome...

Comment: Thanks for the response pennersr. Yes I have stepped through my code before and I just stepped through it all again. My form validation logic (above) is called before the allauth form validation logic. My overriden `LocalSignup.dispatch` function is also called (after `CloseableSignupMixin.dispatch` and after `RedirectAuthenticatedUserMixin.dispatch` and after `SignupView.dispatch`). So the code is definitely called, but regardless it still returns the `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL` HttpRedirectRepose, which I can't quite figure out. Thanks again.

Comment: The super `form_valid` is where the success URL is used: https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/blob/36900f5d1741b00ea6d4e32530c645ebb6c1b9fe/allauth/account/views.py#L114 As you can see the success URL is retrieved (which should invoke your method), and then passed to `complete_signup`, which in turn invokes `perform_login` (https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/blob/36900f5d1741b00ea6d4e32530c645ebb6c1b9fe/allauth/account/utils.py#L80). Your URL should be passed all the time end should end up being used as the redirect URL. Add prints or step through to confirm this.

Comment: Thanks pennersr... I will step through this... really appreciate the response.

Answer (score 3):

In the default view if there is  "next" field in the sign-in form the view, allauth  will automatically redirect to it.

```
<input id="login_redirect" type="hidden" name="next" value="#" />
```

**complete form**

```
      <form method="POST" action="{% url "account_login" %}">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{form}}
        <input  type="hidden" name="next" value="/add_account_select/" />
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Sign IN</button>
      </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to provide an up-to-date answer:

Using django-allauth=0.30.0, the following works nicely in `views.py`

```
from allauth.account.views import SignupView


class LocaLSignupView(SignupView):
    success_url = '/page/to/redirect/to'
```